# Please explain: exponential numeric comparison

Tags: php

I have inherited some old code, and don't understand how this particular element works. It does work, I'm just curious as to what it's doing.

```
define('A', 1);
define('B', 2);
define('C', 4);
define('D', 8);
define('E', 16);
... and so on
```

Then, for each user, an `$options` variable is set as such:

```
$options = 0;
if($_REQUEST['A'] == 'on')
{
    $options |= A;
}
etc
```

Which ultimately ends in an integer which is a total of all set options.  So if I had options A and C, `$options = 5`.

Question 1:

I am unfamiliar with what `|=` is doing, and how it's different (if at all) from:

```
$options = $options + A;
```

Question 2:

Then, we use the following code to see if a user has a certain option stored but I am not sure how this works / what it's doing:

```
$has_c = ($options & C) == C;
$has_d = ($options & D) == D;
```

I gather that it's working by seeing if the total `$options` matches, in someway, the defined globals, but don't understand exactly what `($options & C) == C` is saying.

First impression was it's simply saying:

```
if both $options C equal C
```

But that's obviously not right...

There's obviously a reason why each variable, A, B, C etc double in value too.

What am I not understanding properly?!

Sorry if this doesn't fully explain it, but that's because I'm actually confused how this is doing what it's seemingly doing.

Thanks

Comment: The single `|` and `&` are bitwise operators specifically bitwise OR and bitwise AND respectively.  Here's an introduction to what they mean/do: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Comment: `|` and `&` bitwise `or` and `and`. `$options |= A;` is equals to `$options = $options | A;` The `|` operator turns on a bit if either one is `1/on` and `&` gives `true/1` if both bits are `on/1`. Read more about these operators at (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)[PHP-Manual].

Comment: ($options & C) == C

$options & C does a bitwise AND. All bits in $options and C are compared and only if in both variables the bits at the same positions are 1 the result at this position is 1.
e.g. 1001 (9) & 0111 (7) = 0001 (1)

The result of this is compared to C. Together it means: if all bits in $options are 1 only then will the compare  (== C) will give a "true". Otherwise you will get a "false".